# Django python -- filter() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a query dynamically in forms.py. I store it as a string and then try to filter and return it, but I'm getting the error...

```
filter() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
```

What is going on? Obviously it doesn't like it. Should it be a different data type?

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.db.models import Q

from .models import Incident
from .models import Equipment


class IncidentForm(forms.Form):
    incident_id = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    equipment_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(Equipment.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.TextInput)

    def search(self):

        # cleaning the data
        cust_id = self.cleaned_data.get('incident_id')
        equip_id = self.cleaned_data.get('equipment_id')

        user_input = [cust_id, equip_id]

        # finding blank fields
        i = 0
        lst=[]
        for x in user_input:
            if x != None:
                lst.append(i)
            i += 1

        # setting up query with non blank data
        query = ""
        for x in lst:
            if x == 0:
                query += 'Q(id=cust_id)'
            if x == 1:
                query += 'Q(equipment_id=equip_id)'

        # replace all instances of ')' with ') & '. Also removed the last &
        new_query = query.replace(")", ") & ")
        new_query = new_query[:-3]

        print (new_query)

        return Incident.objects.filter(**new_query)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Q` objects are actual objects. They are not a mini-language you write in strings. You should use:

```
query = Q()

for x in lst:
    if x == 0:
        query &= Q(id=cust_id)
    if x == 1:
        query &= Q(equipment_id=equip_id)

return Incident.objects.filter(query)
```

This looks like an over-engineered way to achieve what you're trying to do, though. How about:

```
def search(self):
    cust_id = self.cleaned_data.get('incident_id')
    equip_id = self.cleaned_data.get('equipment_id')

    qs = Incident.objects.all()
    if cust_id is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(id=cust_id)
    if equip_ip is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(equipement_id=equip_id)

    return qs
```

Comment: thanks! fantastic. Haha it's too obvious that I'm a perl programmer

Answer (score 0):

It's because `filter` does not take a string as a filter. Instead, you should pass it either a `Q` object, or keyword filters (as in the django docs). In your case, you can just create the final query on the fly:

```
query = Q()
for x in lst:
    if x == 0:
        query &= Q(id=cust_id)
    if x == 1:
        query &= Q(equipment_id=equip_id)

print (query)
return Incident.objects.filter(query)
```

The `&=` operator creates new `Q` object that represents `AND` of both left hand-side and right hand-side, inplace.